# How to check for Linux prompt in an expect script?

Tags: jenkins, expect

I'm trying to write an expect script that I can run in a Jenkins job to automate cloning of a GitLFS repo. When I clone a GitLFS repo I get

```
user@hostname $ git clone http://github.company.com/user/test123.git
```

I get

```
Username for 'https://github.company.com': myuser
Password for 'https://myuser@github.company.com':
remote: Counting objects: 66, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 66 (delta 2), reused 8 (delta 2), pack-reused 58
Unpacking objects: 100% (66/66), done.
Downloading bin/at.exe (29.50 KB)
Username for 'https://gitlfs.company.com': myuser
Password for 'https://myuser@gitlfs.company.com':
Downloading bin/foo.exe (29.50 KB)
Username for 'https://gitlfs.company.com': myuser
Password for 'https://myuser@gitlfs.company.com':
Downloading bin/bar.exe (29.50 KB)
Username for 'https://gitlfs.company.com': myuser
Password for 'https://myuser@gitlfs.company.com':
user@hostname $
```

Depending on the repo, I don't know how many times I'm going to get prompted for a username/password. In the repo above, I got promted 4 times. So I want to write an expect script that goes

```
send "git clone http://github.company.com/user/test123.git"
while NOT_EQUAL_TO_PROMPT {
  expect "Username for 'https://gitlfs.company.com':"
  send myuser
  expect "Password for 'https://myuser@gitlfs.company.com':"
  send mypassword
}
```

Any hints on what the "NOT_EQUAL_TO_PROMPT" may look like? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just let Jenkins deal with the checkout for you?  You can store the credentials in Jenkins and it passes them along.

Comment: If GitLFS just prompted me once, that would be the answer. Like I said I don't know how many times GitLFS will prompt me for a username/pw combo.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out @Stephen Newell was partially correct. Jenkins has a GitLFS plugin that will pull the GitLFS objects for me, as discussed in [Git LFS setup in jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45316). All I had to do was store my creds in Jenkins and use them in the Git setup. Thanks!

Comment: Another Suggestion , there can be situations where your need to clone gitLfs repos from scripts and might not use jenkins , for handling such cases , you can set up ssh and clone repos over ssh rather than using http(s)

Comment: Our version of GitLFS does not support the SSH protocol, that is, the .lfsconfig file cannot have an SSH endpoint.